# Why have to concentrate on exhaust gas instead of inlet mixture in Indian Bikes for emission control

Tags: carburetor, o2-sensor, emissions, catalytic-converter, fuel-injectors

I am having Apache RTR 180 (carburetor version) . ***Having a question towards Bharat Stage (BS) (Emission Norms) against bikes.***

Recently went through BS specification.

To achieve this, we are going for the Secondary Air Injection (SAI)  system to both inlet and outlet. (I believe there will be some other great improvements, but this is also taken into account)

Since, the unburnt gas will be potential to environment, we are adding fresh air which will reduce this potential to harm.

But here too, we are concentrating on the "unburnt fuel mixture at outlet" instead of the inlet mixture.

Q1. My question is, *in carburetor version,* why we can not have some feedback sensor in the exhaust (and also make use of the TPS) and alter the fresh air to inlet from SAI accordingly which will reduce this problem in the first place itself. I believe, still carburetor version is not equipped with any of these.

Q2. I believe the FI engines will make use of some feedback sensor*(like o2 sensor,TPS sensor)* to optimise the fuel input. So,by default the FI engines produces less pollution when compared to the carbureted version right?

Q3. I am not considering the catalytic converters since they *are a way to reduce the emission* and will not help in making best(close to 100%) burnt fuel in the cylinder itself.

May I know, what can we do, to make the fuel to burn inside the cylinder close to 100%, which leads to (may be close to) 0% pollution (in both carburetor/FI version in bikes).

Thanks.

Comment: What make, model, and year do you have and what is your maintenance or repair issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here - you ask why we don't use exhaust sensors, then in the second part of the question you note that we do - pretty much all cars for the last 30 years have been FI...

Answer (score 0):

Why not check out the use of the O2 (oxygen) sensors in the exhaust on most cars with catalytic converters and some before...

Subject to your addition of Question 3, the point was not to add a catalytic convertor but to LOOK at the use of the O2 sensors for control...